# Run JUnit test suite from eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for the eclipse IDE, where I need to run a JUnit Test Suite multiple times.
I have tried to select the Run Configuration, but it costs 2s after every launch to wait for the result.

```
ILaunch launch = launchConfiguration.launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE,    monitor);
```

Is there a way to do this faster?